# forkJoin result with map in source

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to use `forkJoin` to get the results of several observables (http requests in real code) together.

One of the source observable (`mainObs` below) has a `map` operator applied so that the output has the same format as the other observables.

My problem is that in the `forkJoin` subscribe, the first result is an observable, and not the output of the first observable.

Here is a sample code, with a [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4r3p8k?devtoolsheight=60).

Am I missing something?

```
import { forkJoin, Observable, of } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

let mainObs = of("main").pipe(map(res => of({success: true, result: res})));

let listOfObservables: Observable<any>[] = [mainObs];

listOfObservables.push(createObs());
listOfObservables.push(createObs());

forkJoin(listOfObservables).subscribe((res: any[]) => {
      console.log(res);
      //Problem: res[0] is an Observable, not a value
      console.log(res[0].success);// <==error
      
    });
    

function createObs()
{
  return of({success: true, result: "dummy"})
}
```

Comment: Use subscribe on res[0].subscribe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`of` creates a new observable. So your `mainObs` return a new observable when it returns.

You probably meant to return the actual result:

```
import { forkJoin, Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

let mainObs = of("main").pipe(map(res => ({ success: true, result: res })));

// creating a typed array helps preventing this problem early.
let listOfObservables: Observable<{ success: boolean; result: string }>[] = [
  mainObs
];

listOfObservables.push(createObs());
listOfObservables.push(createObs());

forkJoin(listOfObservables).subscribe(
  (res: { success: boolean; result: string }[]) => {
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res[0].success); // <== ok
  }
);

function createObs() {
  return of({ success: true, result: "dummy" });
}
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-oatf8n?file=index.ts)

Answer (score 1):

1: `map`

```
of("main").pipe(
  map(res => of({success: true, result: res}))
);
```

This takes the string "main" and then maps that string to an observable. That observable is emitted. What that observable does doesn't matter here as it's never subscribed to.

2: `mergeMap`

```
of("main").pipe(
  mergeMap(res => of({success: true, result: res}))
);
```

This takes the string "main" and then maps that string to an observable. The returned observable is subscribed to and its emissions are passed forward. Finally, `{success: true, result: "main"}` is emitted.

3: Back to `map`

```
of("main").pipe(
  map(res => ({success: true, result: res}))
);
```

This takes the string "main" and maps it to the object `{success: true, result: "main"}`. Then that object is emitted.

---

#2 and #3 have the same final output in these examples. As with most tasks, there is generally more than one way to achieve the same result. #3 is the most performant in this case as you avoid creating an observable and managing it with mergeMap.